# Javascript Slideshow Makes Page Width Large

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here is the javascript for the gallery with some html and css. The slideshow is making the page width really long.

```
http://codepen. io/anon/pen/dPbdav
```

Is there anything I can do to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disable overflow for slideshow element.

Add following css code to your style sheet:

```
#slidy-container{
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: What I did was place them in media queries. You have a really keen eye. Thanks.